# How does Arrays.sort() change the variable passed to it?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Java pass-by-reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

I am a little confused here. How does Arrays.sort(a) modify the value of a?

```
int[] a = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
Arrays.sort(a);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

I thought java was pass by value...

Comment: Also, the jdk comes with the sources, so you can have a look at it if you want to learn more about it.

Comment: Just to expand on the answers: this only works because sort doesn't change the size of the array. If you wanted to do that, you'd have to allocate a new array and couldn't just modify the existing array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, Java is pass-by-value. However, what is getting passed by value here is the *reference* to the array, not the array itself.

Comment: So if you wan't to change the array in another method without changing the original one, you should make a copy of it. correct?

Comment: @Josh: Correct. You can use `a.clone()` to make a copy.

Answer (score 6):

Objects in Java are passed by *value of reference*. So if you pass in an object, it gets a copy of the reference (if you assign that reference to something else, only the parameter is modified, the original object still exists and is referenced by the main program).

[This link demonstrates a bit about passing by value of reference](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html).

```
public void badSwap(Integer var1, Integer var2)
{
  Integer temp = var1;
  var1 = var2;
  var2 = temp;
}
```

Those are references to objects, but they will not be swapped since they are only the internal references in the function scope. However, if you do this:

`var1.doubleValue();`

It will use the *reference* to the original object.

Comment: +1 It's important to remember: only the reference is "cloned", not the object referenced. We take this for granted in most cases but for some reason it causes confusion with arrays.

Comment: Objects in Java are not passed by reference never. When you pass an object to a function, you pass the reference of the object (its value), e.g. in C++ you pass the reference and can do pointer arithmetic, in Java you can't do it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I like to think of it more as a "pseudo-reference". You can use it to access the object and its fields, but it's not comparable to a C-style pointer.

Comment: You can take the concept as you like while you understand it, but just don't go there saying that Java pass by reference when it doesn't. @aix answer explains this in a simple way.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'm afraid I don't understand. I clearly state that it is passed by value of the reference. What part of my answer do you have an issue with?

Comment: Sorry, you were right, I read "or" instead of "of" :( shame on me.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No problem. It happens. :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11752/discussion-between-david-b-and-luiggi-mendoza)

Answer (score 5):

`Arrays.sort` does not modify the variable, it modifies the array object the variable points to.

Answer (score 2):

True, Java always does pass-by-value and for objects, the **reference** of the object by passed by value. Thus, the reference of your array is passed by value.

Answer (score 1):

1. It sorts it.
2. The reference to the array is passed by value. Not the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

The reference to the array is passed by value, so the `sort` method has its own reference that still refers to the same array as `a` references. This means that `sort` can change the content of the same array that `a` references.